# kubernetes: exec: /bin/sh: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I have a pod that is running in Kubernetes. And is working as expected. But I am unable to exec into the container. I tried that, but it throws an error:

```
kubectl exec -it pod/druid-operator-64d9877cbc-q8x7d /bin/sh

error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "ddddddsss": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "echo": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

I ran an inspect on the docker and I do see a CMD

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:fffff",
        "RepoTags": [
            "docker.aa.com/druid-operator:0.0.4",
            "druid-operator:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "docker.aa.com/druid-operator-main@sha256:bbbb"
        ],
        "Parent": "sha256:cccc",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2021-08-02T17:57:44.6184552Z",
        "Container": "dddd",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "8775ee493624",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "nonroot:nonroot",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/certificates.crt"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENTRYPOINT [\"/manager\"]"
            ],
```

Here is a sample of my Docker file

```
FROM docker.aaa.com/cpbuild/go:latest as builder

WORKDIR /workspace

# Install Kubebuilder
ARG OS_ARCH=amd64
ARG KUBEBUILDER_VERSION=2.3.1
RUN curl -L -O "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/releases/download/v${KUBEBUILDER_VERSION}/kubebuilder_${KUBEBUILDER_VERSION}_linux_${OS_ARCH}.tar.gz"
RUN tar -zxvf kubebuilder_${KUBEBUILDER_VERSION}_linux_${OS_ARCH}.tar.gz
RUN mv kubebuilder_${KUBEBUILDER_VERSION}_linux_${OS_ARCH} kubebuilder && mv kubebuilder /usr/local/
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/kubebuilder/bin

COPY . .

# Build
RUN go mod download
RUN go fmt ./...
RUN go vet ./...
RUN go test ./...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on go build -a -o manager main.go

# Use distroless as minimal base image to package the manager binary
# Refer to https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless for more details

FROM docker.aaa.com/distroless/static:nonroot
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=builder /workspace/manager .
USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/manager"]
```

Let me know what I am missing. Or if any other data points are needed, I can share. Thanks in advance

Comment: From this behavior we can surmise that `docker.aaa.com/distroless/static:nonroot` does not have `/bin/sh` installed.

Comment: Thanks. I figured something like that would be the issue. Do you have any doc or idea on how to install it? It will be of great help.

Comment: You can build with the `debug` images according to the link you provided for distroless on github: they provide a busybox shell.  Not having a shell on the image is kind of the *point* of minimal images, so if you *want* a shell, you might ask yourself why you're using a base image without one  https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless#debug-images

Comment: The reverse of @DanielFarrell's question: if the image doesn't have a `/bin/sh`, it probably has almost nothing beyond the `/manager` binary.  What are you hoping to be able to do with a `kubectl exec` shell?